# Whats the meaning of A obj = new A(new B);?

Tags: java, object, oop

**Approach 1**

AppMain.java

```
A obja = new A(new B());
```

RandomClass.java

```
B b; 
pubic A(B b){
this.b = b;
}
```

**Approach 2**

AppMain.java

```
B objb = new B();
A obja = new A(objb);
```

RandomClass.java

```
//same code
```

Is approach1 and approach2 same?

Answer (score 1):

With one minor difference, the two approaches are the same (except you would need `new A(new B())` instead of `new A(new B)` in the first approach). The difference is that in the second approach you end up with a separate reference (the variable `objb`) to the `B` object that is supplied to the `A` constructor.

Comment: In approach 1 , the reference 'obja' is pointing to two objects(new A and new B)?

Comment: @PradiptaGhatak - The reference `obja` is pointing to the new `A` object. Internally, the `A` object may or may not maintain a reference to the `B` object that was passed to the constructor; whether it does or not depends on how the `A` object is defined. References in Java always are either `null` or refer to a single object.

Answer (score 0):

`new B` is a compiler error. Approach 1 therefore fails, approach 2 does not - they are not the same.

If you intended that to be `new B()` but you were a little careless in posting the question - then these are entirely the same. `new B()` means: Make a new B object, and this expression then evaluates to a reference that points at this newly made object. With `new A(new B())` you then pass a copy of this reference to the A constructor. With `B objb = ...` you assign a copy of this reference to a local variable, and then invoke the A constructor, handing a copy of this reference to it.

That boils down to the exact same thing, in other words.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for pointing out the missing () :)